# AD FS Authentication

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication

I have a more theoretical question about AD FS. If I use it as a STS (Security token service) for accessing some internal company information from outside of private company network (over internet), using Claim-based authentication, can I decide exactly what credentials will be used for authentication or is it pre-set by Active Directory policies? To be more accurate, could I authenticate form a device that is not registered in AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to authenticate against ADFS from outside the corporate domain, you should install the [ADFS proxy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/01/05/understanding-the-ad-fs-2-0-proxy.aspx) in your DMZ.

ADFS can be used to authenticate users against the Active Directory domain it is installed in, or trust tokens coming from a federated STS.

So, if you have a web application that trusts tokens issued by ADFS, you can use security protocols like [WS-Federation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498017.aspx), [WS-Trust](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.3/ws-trust.html) or [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (in ADFS 3.0) to get a token from ADFS and use it to authenticate against your web application.

Device registration is not required to use these protocols.

HTH.

Comment: thanx, this answers my question